# Neo4jrb: undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

When creating two classes and a relationship between them;

(Rough example)

```
class User
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
  property :email, type: String
end
```

---

```
class Group
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode
  property :name, type: String
  property :email, type: String

  has_many :in, :users, type:BELONGS_TO, model_class: :User
end
```

Calling `@group.users.each ...` works if there is a user in that group (an existing node-edge relationship), but if there is not, Rails fails with `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

What's the most performant way to fail gracefully when there is no connected node?

Comment: This shouldn't happen, it should behave like an empty enumerable. Can you review your code for a typo? I can see one in the code sample you provided, `type:BELONGS_TO :`, though that would give a very different error... Still, give it another once-over.

Comment: I'll do you one better.
I've gone straight from `rails new` to a project with the problem.
https://github.com/Joshfindit/Neo4jrb_undefined-method-each-for-nil-NilClass

Comment: Going over this, I noticed that in trying to simplify the question, I mis-stated something.
I'm attempting to call `@group.users.each` NOT Group.users.each (following what rails uses when generating a scaffolded view)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to hear back from what you found from Chris' suggestion, but adding an `all` in the chain might help:

```
Group.all.users.each...
```